# Identificar se todos caracteres são iguais

Tags: javascript, string

Tenho o seguinte código que funciona perfeitamente.

Nele possuo uma *string* e verifico se todos os caracteres dela são iguais ou não:

```
var numbers = '1111121111',
    firstNumber = numbers.substr(0,1),
    numbersEquals = true;

for(let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if (numbers[i] != firstNumber) numbersEquals = false;
}
console.log('numbersEquals = ' + numbersEquals)
```

Existe uma forma mais fácil ou um método pronto para fazer isso?

Acho que estou usando muito código para fazer algo simples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), faça o seguinte:

```
/^(.)\1+$/.test(sua_string)
```

Isso retorna `true` ou `false` a depender se todos os caracteres são iguais ou não.

```
/^(.)\1+$/.test("xxxx"); // true
/^(.)\1+$/.test("xxxy"); // false
```

`test()` está desde o [ECMA 3rd edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) (1999). Funcionará basicamente em todos os browsers.

Comment: Boa! Não conhecia esse Método! :)

Answer (score 8):

Com ECMA6, é possível usando [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
const unicos = [...new Set(numbers)]
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var numbers = '1111112111';

if (new Set(numbers).size > 1)
  console.log("Todos os valores não são iguais");
else
  console.log("Todos os valores são iguais");
```

**Edit:**

Como @bfavaretto sugeriu, é possível obter o [número](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size) de elemento no objeto Set.

Comment: @Lucas não conheço essa notação ainda '[...new Set(numbers)]'

Comment: @alan agora você conhece :)

Comment: @alan Tem duas coisas aí, se quiser pesquisar: o `Set`, e o *spread operator* `...`.

Comment: valeu @LucasCosta! :)

Comment: Eu estou dando uma estudada nisso agora @bfavaretto valeu! ;)

Answer (score 8):

Tem muitas maneiras de fazer isso. Não acho a sua errada, é bem clara e didática. Mas tem maneiras mais curtas, como a do Mr Felix. Convertendo pra array dá para fazer uns truques também, por exemplo:

```
var numbers = '1111121111';
numbers.split('').every(function(num, i, arr) { return num == arr[0] }); // false
```

Ou ainda mais curto em ES-2015:

```
const numbers = '1111121111';
[...numbers].every( (num, i, arr) => num == arr[0] ); // false
```

Answer (score 5):

Eu faria exatamente do que jeito que fez porque deve ser a solução mais rápida. Mas tem várias alternativas, uma delas:

```js
var numbers = '1111121111';
console.log('numbersEquals = ' + (numbers.replace(new RegExp(numbers.substr(0, 1), 'g'), "").length == 0));
numbers = '1111111111';
console.log('numbersEquals = ' + (numbers.replace(new RegExp(numbers.substr(0, 1), 'g'), "").length == 0));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Equals.js).

Comment: Isso de retornar a quantidade de ocorrências do RegExp eu n sabia. Acho q isso ainda vai me ser útil para outras situações! ;)