# Validação de numeros repetidos?

Tags: javascript

o que está acontecendo é que as pessoas estão colocando 000000000 em cada campo e está passando, só esta bloqueando se for em branco, alguem é ajuda a bloquear os numeros sequenciais de 0 a 9 ex: 0000 telefone (00) 0000-0000 ...

```js
function valida_form (){

if(document.getElementById("dados03").value.length < 14){
alert('Por favor, preencha o campo Telefone.');
document.getElementById("dados03").focus();
return false
}

if(document.getElementById("dados04").value.length < 7){
alert('Por favor, preencha a sua Assinatura Eletrônica.');
document.getElementById("dados04").focus();
return false
}

if(document.getElementById("dados05").value.length < 4){
alert('Por favor, preencha sua Senha do Cartão.');
document.getElementById("dados05").focus();
return false
}
```

Comment: E o que queres impedir? se **todos** os numeros forem iguais, ou qual o minimo repetidos para rejeitar?

Comment: Já viste esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/156832/129 ?

Comment: ex: telefone está aceitando telefone (99) 9999-9999 senha de 4 digitos : 0000 assinatura: 55555555, quero bloquear isso mesmo que seja real !

Comment: Leonardo, acho que a pergunta é o mesmo que a outra que linkei. Dá uma olhada, e se achares que é diferente explica melhor porquê para podermos ajudar melhor.

Comment: cara, aquilo está em javascript ? estou validando campos em html

Comment: não faço ideia de como aplicar aquilo :P

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61328/discussion-between-leonardo-ribeiro-and-sergio).

Comment: Relecionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172410/identificar-se-todos-caracteres-s%c3%a3o-iguais

Comment: O recomendável é que validações sejam feitas no backend, seja la qual for a linguagem que esteja usando para salvar as informações..... validações em frontend (vide javascript) se tornam inseguras se por exemplo, o cliente desativar o javascript do navegador

Comment: @LucasCosta o unico problema é que não sei aplicar isso ao meu codigo... :P

Comment: Algo mais ou menos assim: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzyjetds/2/

Comment: @MarceloBoni ficou top amigo, só o alerta que está aparecendo 2x

Comment: @MarceloBoni, primeiro eu fiz ele sem nada, depois usei tudo 0 e apareceu 2x, mas está muito bom, muito obrigado!

Comment: igual está no seu gif ai, quando você aperta uma vez no ok, aparece outro

Comment: desculpa, erro meu, no meu form tinha um valida.... também !

Comment: @MarceloBoni, não sei porque aparece o alerta e ai eu aperto ok, e ele submete a pagina sem eu corrigir, não volta pra mesma pagina para a correção... tem noção do que é isso ?

Comment: @LeonardoRibeiro sugiro que crie uma pergunta com todo o seu código, omitindo aquilo que seja de informação confidencial, tipo nome da empresa, links, senhas e etc